# Angular 2+ route redirectTo as a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have the following route config in the Angular app:

```
{
  path: ParentComponent.path,
  component: ParentComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: getDefaultChildRoute()
    },
    {
      path: ':mode/:year/:month/:day',
      component: ChildComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

The getDefaultChildRoute() function returns a string like this:

```
export function getDefaultChildRoute(): string {
  const urlArray = ['a', '2019', '02'];
  return urlArray.join('/');
}
```

The problem seems to be that the `redirectTo` expects a string, but not a method to call (even if it returns a string). If I substitute that method call with a placeholder string, it works alright.

There is an issue about it at github already: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13373

Using an arrow function directly at the `redirectTo` throws Typescript error '()=>string is not assignable to type string'.

Any ideas?

Comment: A function works for me, the arrow one won't work because you are not making it self executable, invoke it like: (() => {})(). See here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhtvlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Somehow it works on a click, but not on a load?.. Tried to invoke the arrow function like you said - no type error, but it still won't redirect.

Comment: What is version of angular you are using? I tried with an empty path and it still works on a load. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k95xjv?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Angular 7.2.1 + Typescript 3.3.3 Well, this is strange.

Comment: @xyz: It actually worked for a while! However, when compiling with AOT flag, it fails with the following message: `ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getDefaultChildRoute' was called in 'appRoutes'
    'appRoutes' calls 'getDefaultChildRoute' at app/app-routing.module.ts(67,42).` I need to provide it, but am stuck with incorrect syntax. (If you reply, please write it as an answer, so I can upvote it and mark it as correct, if it is ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
redirectTo: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    const urlArray = ['a', '2019', '02'];
    return urlArray.join('/');
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's what I've mean with an arrow function. I get TS2322 Error: `type() => string is not assignable to type 'string'`